# Do I need a license to drive a moter vehicle

Tags: traffic

Do I need a license to drive moter vehicle because I was pulled over and received probation for 1 yr or in tell I paid the tickets off in witch I was charged with driveing on suspend licence feluar to matain insurance on my vehicle any way the tickets were 700 dollors total but I haven't paid because I was traveling not driveing but when I told the cop that he told me I was crazy and that the law did not exist but he's wrong right or am I wrong plz let me know what paper work I need to back up what I was doing bye traveling not driveing ty for your time and answers on these hear issues. God Bless the US and you .Brandon L.

Comment: Your question is almost incomprehensible at the moment, but I will guess at your meaning. It is possible that you had a defence to the original charge, that you were a passenger not the driver. Either you did not mention that at the trial or the court rejected it; whichever it was, it is too late now. Fines imposed by the court have to be paid, whatever your opinion; if your licence was suspended, you are not allowed to drive even if the suspension was wrongful (of which I see no evidence).

Comment: @TimLymington the fact that the OP tries to make a distinction between "driving" and "travelling" (and the fact that he was fined for "driving on suspended licence") makes me think that he is trying to use the trope that the right to travel through the USA implies a right to drive... see for example https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/26420/legal-to-drive-without-a-license?rq=1

Comment: There was a movie about an old man who did travel without license - using a ride-on lawnmower. I wouldn't surprised if that was legal.

Comment: @gnasher729: It isn't in Florida, at least. There is a surprisingly large corpus of case law on this point, much of it covering driving while intoxicated: I recommend the summary at [Lowering the Bar](http://loweringthebar.net/2019/05/surge-in-dsuwi-cases.html).

Answer (score 6):

You are completely in the wrong.

It is against the law to operate a motor vehicle without a license. It is against the law to have a motor vehicle that is not insured. It is against the law to violate the conditions of your probation which almost certainly provide that you are not allowed to operate a motor vehicle until your license is reinstated and you have insurance in force. Your personal belief that you didn't break the law is not a valid reason not to pay a fine on a ticket that is ratified by a court.

The cop was right when he told you that you were crazy.

Comment: Although, to be fair - the police officer is unlikely to be a qualified psychologist or psychiatrist so his diagnosis is likely suspect

Comment: @DaleM In that context "crazy" is not a psychological diagnosis, it is a statement that someone is disconnected from the way that the world works to an absurd extent.